# Cannot change height of BottomSheetBehavior dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

When the button clicked, I want the height of Bottom Sheet change as seen in the image below. I tried multiple solutions none worked well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like:

- Set the maximum height in XML and expand on button click
- Call `bottomsheet.setY(float)`